# Ember.js Rails Error while loading route:

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm currently reading the Master Time and Space Ember.js tutorial and trying to build the sample application. I'm building the ember app with rails using the ember-rails gem.

I have followed the instructions for building my index route, controller, model and template. However, my index.hbs template is not being rendered due to this error that I am receiving in the console:

```
 Error while loading route: undefined logToConsole
```

this function logToConsole is defined within the ember.js file that the gem compiles for you.

My router is defined as **app/assets/javascripts/routes/app_router.js**

```
TimeTravel.Router.reopen({
   location: "history"
});

 TimeTravel.Router.map(function(){
    this.route("index", {path: "/"});
});
```

The index route is defined as **app/assets/javascripts/routes/index_route.js**

```
  TimeTravel.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return this.store.find('trip');
   }  
});
```

The controller **app/assets/javascripts/controllers/index_controller.js**

```
  TimeTravel.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  });
```

Can someone please explain this error? Or at least point out some good debugging tools for ember. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this causes the error, but typically with ArrayControllers, I think the route's model would be looked up using "findAll" instead of just "find".

Comment: Jason's comment is wrong find - the way you did it is right.  Everything you have provided looks good except for location: "history" - which I haven't used and can't comment on.  As to debugging the best tool is the chrome extension: ember inspector which is a great little tool.  Other than that I use chrome developer tools to debug my code and sometimes step through the source code to understand what is going on.

Comment: I would also check if you've loaded ember, ember data, jquery and handlebars correctly in your page.  Also if you are using Chrome Canary I sometimes get some weird error messages that go away in a different browser.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue.